# What is the correct time complexity of the following code

Tags: time-complexity

I was wondering what is the correct time complexity expressed in terms of big O on this type of loop:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(int j=1;j*i<=n;j++)
        // O(1) code here
```

The inner loops will make $n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{3} + \dots + \frac{n}{n}$. I know that this type of formula is $O(n \log n)$, so is this the correct time complexity on this piece of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: @old Either edit or explain why. Just saying "You should do this other thing" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$n+\frac{n}{2}+\cdots +\frac{n}{n}$$

$$= n(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n})$$

Now it is a well-known fact that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n} \le c \log n$, where $c$ is some constant.

$$\le cn(\log n)$$

So the overall Runtime is $\mathcal{O}{(n \log n)}$.

Answer (score 4):

The number of times that the body of the inner loop runs is exactly
$$
T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor.
$$
This is sequence [A006218](https://oeis.org/A006218) in OEIS, where it is stated that
$$
T(n) = n(\log n + 2\gamma - 1) + \tilde O(n^{131/416}).
$$
The exact magnitude of the error term isn't known, but it cannot be reduced below $\tilde O(n^{1/4})$.

For more references, see the Wikipedia article on [Dirichlet's divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet's_divisor_problem).